# Duplicate reputation list appearing

Tags: support, bug

When I get the [rep notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220577/bala?tab=reputation), I used to open the [reputation tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220577/bala?tab=reputation), but initially it shows the duplicate list, which makes me confusing and once I refreshed the page it render correctly. It happening only when the reputation changes.

> [image]
>
> [image]

another screenshots

> [image]